# Convert date/time from human readable format

Tags: r

I've an human readable date/time : « Wed Sep 23 07:21:37 +0000 2009 »

I simply try since yesterday to convert it to a date/time object.

```
pb.txt <- "Wed Sep 23 07:21:37 +0000 2009"
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
format(pb.date, tz="WET",usetz=TRUE)
[1] NA
```

May I use instead strptime() ? 
What's wrong ? An encoding problem ?
And above all, why Google can't help me to find a solution ? Nobody has ever done it ? :)

Thanks for your help,

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: What is your locale (`?Sys.getlocale`)?

Comment: Change your locale to an English language one. Names of weekdays and months are localized.

Comment: How can I do that ? :)

Comment: Reading the help page I've pointed out to you might help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ! Thank you very much Roland for your help.
The problem was the names of weekdays and months (in human readable format) which are obviously localized. So, you just need to change your locale to an English language one.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.utf8");
format(pb.date, tz="WET",usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2009-09-23 08:21:37 WEST"
```

Joshua has also seen a other little mistake... which don't solve this problem, but probably a next one. Thanks for him too ! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're ignoring the timezone in the `as.POSIXct` call, so your system's timezone is being used (to the best R can determine what it is).  My guess is that the time doesn't exist in `"WET"` because of daylight saving time.

```
# include the timezone offset in the format
(pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"))
# [1] "2009-09-23 02:21:37 CDT"
format(pb.date, tz="WET",usetz=TRUE)
# [1] "2009-09-23 08:21:37 WEST"
```

Comment: Thanks... but nothing change. :/ By timezone offset, do you mean the %z tag that I forgot ?

Comment: @jonathan: yes, that's what the "+0000" represents. Please edit the output from `sessionInfo()` into your question.

Comment: the question is refreshed with the output from 'sessionInfo()'. :)